# Image upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, zip

How do I upload images and zip files in RoR? I am a newbie. So please help.
Give me both the view and the controller code example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nav,

Try the paperclip plugin, you can read about it here http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip

Comment: Paperclip is not currently well supported on Windows.  So if you have a mixed dev/deployment environment beware.

Answer (score 9):

We prefer [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for image uploads in Rails. Very easy to integrate and very modular.
The following post describes a solution for image uploading using CarrierWave while image transformations are done seamlessly in the cloud. Uploaded images are stored in the cloud and delivered through a CDN. 
No need to install RMagick, MiniMagick and ImageMagick.
http://cloudinary.com/blog/ruby_on_rails_image_uploads_with_carrierwave_and_cloudinary

Answer (score 8):

suggest checking out the Railscast for [paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip).

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://vantulder.net/rails/magick/) is also pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend paperclip, and the patch that allows you to store the content in the database instead of the file system

http://patshaughnessy.net/paperclip-database-storage

the link has the view and controller examples that you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I prefer carrierwave is better to upload images easily.
Here's [github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) , and [railscasts page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast) for quick start.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [attachment_fu](http://wiki.github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu). It allows you to save your uploaded file to the filesystem, database, or Amazon S3. It also allows you to select which image processor is used, such as RMagick or Minimagick.

The link provides better code than I could here.

Comment: As a side note, I prefer paperclip to attachment_fu. It is more opinionated with sensible defaults a la "The Rails Way"